# C# Copy FileStream to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, filestream

I am having problem to copy FileStream to HttpPostedFileBase. My code is something like this.

```
HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = null;    
FileStream f = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Path"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(f);
f.Close();
```

However I can read file but having error when try to copy f to postedFile. Please correct me if I am doing wrong or any problem in this code block.
Furthermore, I am getting this exception:

"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here by copying the file stream to the posted file? Posted file is something that gets given from the client (when the user uploads a file)

Comment: You should always note on what line the exception were actually thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your postedFile is null - this is why you are getting the null reference exception.